# How to set a login cookie in django?

Tags: django, cookies, authentication, member

How do I set_cookie with the username of the member that is logged in to my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement this by using the [session middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), make sure to enable it in your project. I recommend you to use [django.contrib.auth](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) to manage sessions though. It manages sessions in the database which is a lot safer than just saving the username in a cookie

Comment: Can you give me a code or something, becuz imma new in Django branch ;d

Comment: In addition to [what Rodrigue said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898408/how-to-set-a-login-cookie-in-django/4898612#4898612), make sure that the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list in settings.py contains 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', although it's the default so it should be there if you haven't touched anything. take a look in the documentation to the login() method and the @login_required helper.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of how to do it using middleware

```
class UserCookieMiddleWare(object):
    """
    Middleware to set user cookie
    If user is authenticated and there is no cookie, set the cookie,
    If the user is not authenticated and the cookie remains, delete it
    """

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        #if user and no cookie, set cookie
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.COOKIES.get('user'):
            response.set_cookie("user", 'Hello Cookie')
        elif not request.user.is_authenticated() and request.COOKIES.get('user'):
            #else if if no user and cookie remove user cookie, logout
            response.delete_cookie("user")
        return response
```

Comment: should I disable the default ones? Not clear if there is going to be a conflict

Answer (score 3):

The [django.contrib.auth](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) app. is the best way to add a login feature to your site. This app. uses the [django.contrib.sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) app and middleware.

The session middleware will look after setting a cookie in the user's browser for you. Then, in your code, it means that you will need to decorate your views to force users to login:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Inside your view, you will then have access to

- `request.session`, which is a `dict` where you can store data across the session
- `request.user`, which is [user](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#api-reference) object

I advise you to read the docs. Documentation is one of the best parts of Django

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie Please refer this link for individual arguments of inbuilt function.

Create signal.py in app. where your user model is present or add in main project directory and Add below snippet in signal.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete, post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.dispatch import Signal
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in # it signal for post login 
from django.shortcuts import render

@receiver(user_logged_in) # Decorator of receiving signal while user going to logged in
def post_login(sender, user, request, response, **kwargs):
    response.set_cookie('team', 'india') # This will set cookie
    return response
```

In given snippet, default response will come in argument, so direct redirect to that response, if you want to change then render other template using render/redirect django.shortcuts methods like below,

response = render(request, 'base.html', {})

Comment: This does not seem to work: post_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'