# How to create a cookie after login using Django?

Tags: python, django

I wonder how is the best way to create a cookie after login into Django. I have an issue that it's necessary to store some (non sensitive) user information in a cookie that another system (running in a subdomain) will read it. I need do something looking into the performance, so I don't want call the function every page request.

I tried to use **login signal** calling a function to set a cookie using **set_cookie**. But I figured out that is necessary to return **HttpResponse** to the browser. I am not sure if it's possible using the **signal**. How is the best approach in this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a login cookie in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898408/how-to-set-a-login-cookie-in-django)

Comment: I am not sure that this is duplicated answer. Using process_response in the middleware every page request will call this function. So, I think that this is not the best approach. The best way to solve that is calling the function just one time, immediately after the login action.