# Django: Properly Setting Cookies For Login

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I am new to Django's sessions, and i tried to make a login cookie for my website. User's on my website register via social website ( steam in this case ), For that i have different functions: `Index` view, Login, `LoginProcess`.

## Information:

`Index` view is a homepage (`127.0.0.1`), `Login` function redirects user to `LoginProcess`, in this process, i have set a cookie.

```
request.set_cookie(key='logged', value=True)
```

`request` is instance that all 3 functions have in my code, I have set the logged in key to True, which should be read by Index function.

Index Function:

```
def index(request):
    if request.COOKIES.get('logged') == True:
        return HttpResponse("1 - User is logged in")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("0 - User is not logged in)
```

Unfortunately, this brings up statement 0 (User is not logged in), even if i am logged in the website, the value of logged key is `None`.

---

## Problem:

`Index` function cannot detect that `logged` cookie was registered in `LoginProcess` function.

## Question:

I am going to save the username in cookie as well, so system can determine which users data should it use, i know it is very bad for the client-side cookies, What's the best way of doing it?

How could i fix this problem? Is there any better way to set up login cookie? Is there any other better way to set up login session?

So basically, how could i set cookie in the first function and get it's value from the second function?

**Note**: There is no problem with authentication, my main concerns are to properly set cookies.

Comment: Django as a rather complete and extensible auth system (`contrib.auth`), why not using it instead of reinventing the wheel ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers as i mentioned in my post, i am using social authentication, Custom made system gives me more features and is easier for me overall.

Comment: As I mentioned `contrib.auth` _is extensible_ and there are examples of social auth integration (even some pluggable apps FWIW). Also consider that any pluggable app needing auth and/or permissions will very likely (thats an understatement) depends on `contrib.auth`. But if you really love pain and prefer to roll your own, you can still have a look at how `contrib.auth` handles that part of the problem.

Comment: I use steamauth for authentication, but that's not the problem at all. All i need is to properly set the login cookie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am still reading it wrong, but it is impossible to set the value on a request's cookie.

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'
```

but if I assume you meant `response.set_cookie(key='logged', value=True)` (note `response`), then this works for me.

```
# sets the cookie if not set.
print request.COOKIES
if request.COOKIES.get('logged'):
    return HttpResponse("1 - User is logged in")
else:
    response = HttpResponse("0 - User is not logged in")
    response.set_cookie('logged', True)
    return response
```

Comment: I had `request` as instance of all functions, it worked, but i don't know the main point of it, thanks for correcting me. But in this case, i set cookie in other view function (`LoginProcess`) and get it's value from `Index` view function.

Comment: Is it because you check `== True`, while the cookie is set as `'True'` becasue cookies are strings? (my example does not check for a boolean.)

Comment: mine did and gave else's statement, `request.COOKIES.get('logged')` contains `None` in this case. is it possible to set the cookie in first function and access it from second?

Comment: It should probably check for `== 'True'`, but since it's not the problem, what's in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES?

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]`

Comment: Looks okay... and where you say `LoginProcess` sets a cookie, I hope that response is sent to the client at least once, can you confirm that?

Comment: This is important part of `LoginProcess` with cookies:      `for search in User.objects.all():
      if user in search:
       request.set_cookie(key='logged', value=True)
      else:
        user = User(steamid=steamid, username=user, joined=timezone.now(), avatar=user.avatar_medium, userurl=user.profile_url)
        request.set_cookie(key='logged', value=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`

Comment: Yeah fella you need to set the cookie in the response that is `response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')`

Comment: will this apply to index function as well? so it can read the cookie

Comment: This applies to all cookies to intend to set, all responses you intend to create, and all view functions you have. `set_cookie` is an instruction you add to a response that tells the client to actually set the cookie, so wherever you want to set the cookie, that response must return to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirily sure about your question, but if you want to set a cookie besides the session_id, WHEN the user is logged in you can also use middleware. Like also suggested here:

[How to set a login cookie in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898408/how-to-set-a-login-cookie-in-django)